# Angularjs Linechart directive won't load $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the resource

```
hq.factory('AvgUsersPerWeek', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/HQ/Graph/GetLoggedinUsersPerWeek')
});
```

The controller

```
hq.controller('AvgUsersPerWeekCtrl', function ($scope, AvgUsersPerWeek) {

    $scope.xkey = 'Period';

    $scope.ykeys = ['CountUsers'];

    $scope.labels = ['Aantal'];

    $scope.myModel = AvgUsersPerWeek.query();

    /*
    //example dataset that works, the fetched data has the same structure
    [ 
    { "Period": "2013-04", "CountUsers": 2407 },
    { "Period": "2013-03", "CountUsers": 3351 },
    { "Period": "2013-02", "CountUsers": 2469 },
    { "Period": "2013-01", "CountUsers": 2246 },
    { "Period": "2012-12", "CountUsers": 3171 },
    { "Period": "2012-11", "CountUsers": 2155 },
    { "Period": "2012-10", "CountUsers": 1226 },
    { "Period": "2012-09", "CountUsers": 2245 }
    ]; */


})
```

Fyi. If i substitute AvgUsersPerWeek.query() with the dataset below it, it works. So something is going wrong with my resource (which gets fetched (Fiddler). But the value isn't getting insert into my chart.

I have double checked, the example dataset has the same structure as the dataset fetched by the $resource.

I have not enclosed the HTML because it works. I suppose there's something in the way i use $resources.

Comment: What is the result of the query? Could you log the `AvgUsersPerWeek.query()`?

Comment: [{"Period":"34","CountUsers":19},{"Period":"35","CountUsers":9}] . I replaced these values with my testdata to check if the chart got loaded and it does.

Comment: Ok so you have the correct data. But $resource use promises which are async so the promise may be not resolved when the scope is initialized

Comment: I based my code on : http://jsbin.com/saxuzirimepe/1/edit , perhaps that would help to see what's wrong. The dataset there, i encapsulated it within a $resource and that doesn't work

Comment: Did you made your own jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Kinda hard, because i don't have the dataset online..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f3y8qbun/ (doesn't fully work, but it contains all the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess  you are missing a callback in your resource. You should do something like this in your controller:

```
AvgUsersPerWeek.query(function(data) {
    $scope.myModel = data;
  });
```

See [this page](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html) for more info

In your directive the data is probably not updated and you should add a watcher (or observe for attributes) in the directive to update the data according to change from the resource

```
$attrs.$observe('data', function(newVal){
    console.log(newVal);
    // The rest of your link
})
```

Here is an updated version of your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3v7nuys/)

Question author Update: I changed the directive to use :

```
$scope.$watch(attrs.data, function (newVal) { ...
```

And it works, thx!

Comment: I encapsulated it like :  

AvgUsersPerWeek.query(function (data) {
        $scope.myModel = data;
    });

And it still doesn't render the chart (no error either). Fyi, i based my code on : http://jsbin.com/ayUgOYuY/5/edit

Comment: The jsfiddle does'nt seem to work. But the directive for the linechart, uses a link. The data in the link hasn't been loaded yet, so the graph is trying to load an empty dataset. According to me, it loads to soon. Here is practicly all of the code in a jsfiddle (including the linechart directive)